# C# Memory Leak on Raspberry Pi Thermostat

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  While I am not new to C#, I haven't ever used it to access GPIO, nor deployed to Linux.

It is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, using dotnet 6.0. On launch, it is using nearly 200MB of virtual memory, 71 of Private. It runs for a little over a day and crashes. I have looked at the top reasons for memory leaks, tried to optimize it over and over, and it still is growing in size till it gets an OOM error. It seems pretty simple, but it grows by about 1 MB every 4-5 minutes.

In my Main() function, I have this:

```
while (true) {
    var TH = new TempHumidity();
    TH.RefreshSensorData();
    TH = null;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    counter++;
    if (counter == 10) {
        GC.Collect();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

This is the function it is calling. I used to have it as a public static, then moved to private. I realize I could slow down the while loop, but it is easier to debug the faster the leak happens. Ideally, this would be able to run indefinitely, so any leak would eventually be fatal, to my pets that is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Iot.Device.DHTxx;

namespace TempControl
{
    public class TempHumidity
    {
        public static List<Sensor> SensorData = new List<Sensor>();
        public  void RefreshSensorData()
        {
            int[] pins = new int[] { 10, 9, 11, 5, 6, 13, 19, 26 };
            var TH = new TempHumidity();
            foreach (var pin in pins)
            {
                try
                {
                    TH.GetPinData( pin);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
            
        }
        private  void GetPinData(int pin) {
            using (Dht11 dht = new Dht11(pin))
            {
                double testVal = dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit;
                if (dht.IsLastReadSuccessful)
                {

                    bool foundMatch = false;
                    foreach (var sensor in SensorData)
                    {
                        if (pin == sensor.pin)
                        {
                            foundMatch = true;
                            sensor.humidity = dht.Humidity.Percent;
                            sensor.temperature = dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit;
                            if (sensor.maxTemp < dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit)
                            {
                                sensor.maxTemp = dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit;
                            }
                            if (sensor.minTemp > dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit)
                            {
                                sensor.minTemp = dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit;
                            }
                            if (sensor.maxHumidity < dht.Humidity.Percent)
                            {
                                sensor.maxHumidity = dht.Humidity.Percent;
                            }
                            if (sensor.minHumidity > dht.Humidity.Percent)
                            {
                                sensor.minHumidity = dht.Humidity.Percent;
                            }
                            sensor.last_updated = DateTime.Now;
                            sensor.reading_good = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (foundMatch == false)
                    {
                        Sensor currentSensor = new Sensor();
                        currentSensor.pin = pin;
                        currentSensor.temperature = dht.Temperature.DegreesFahrenheit;
                        currentSensor.humidity = dht.Humidity.Percent;
                        SensorData.Add(currentSensor);
                        currentSensor = null;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var sensor in SensorData)
                    {
                        if (pin == sensor.pin)
                        {
                            var TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
                            int diff = Convert.ToInt32(TimeNow.Subtract(sensor.last_updated).TotalSeconds);
                            if (diff > 3)
                            {
                                sensor.reading_good = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class Sensor
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public int pin { get; set; }
            public double temperature { get; set; }
            public double humidity { get; set; }
            public DateTime last_updated;
            public DateTime last_reported;
            public double minTemp = 200;
            public double minHumidity = 200;
            public double maxTemp = 0;
            public double maxHumidity = 0;
            public bool reading_good = false;
            public bool relay_on = false;
        }

        public class SensorList
        {
            public List<Sensor> data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I have disabled virtually every other area of code execution, which really is just the relay control based on these readings. I am not sure if my problem is using a bad package that has memory leaks, or if I am not doing things properly on my side.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call GC.Collect like that, you are likely rushing the GC, pushing objects into Gen1 and Gen2 too quickly. Similarly, setting variables to null immediately before they go out of scope is useless (though it's hard for that to bite you). Have you gone through your code and made sure that you Dispose every object that is disposable? My normal recommendation is to use the .NET memory counters in PerfMon to help you figure out what's going on. With Rasp. PI that's probably a useless rec.

Comment: Has `GC.Collect();` always been in your code or is it something you added to try to resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks guys, I just added the `GC.Collect();` in an effort to clean it up. @Flydog57 I don't know that anything I have is disposable, that isn't anything I have had to worry about in the past. In reality, every part of my executing code is shown already, so if you see something I should be disposing of, please let me know.

Comment: Generally, anything that does I/O is going to be Disposable (just because).  My guess is that nearly everything you do with a Raspberry PI is doing I/O.

Comment: The library that accesses the GPIO was already in a using statement, so I assumed it would GC properly, but I added a .Dispose() at the end for good measure. After running it for 15 minutes, it still grew by 3MB

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you have

```
public static List<SensorList> SensorData = new List<SensorList>();
```

and keep adding values with the following statement:

`SensorData.Add(currentSensor);`

Static fields exist for the lifetime of the program, and aren't garbage collected - unless you set it to null at some point (but no such code was posted).

It's not necessary to re-create an instance of your class every 500 ms - use the same instance. Try the following:

The following uses a .NET 5 (Console) project:

**Note**: Not sure if this is the NuGet package that you used, but to be able to compile, I downloaded/installed NuGet package: `nanoFramework.Iot.Device.Dhtxx`

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Iot.Device.DHTxx;

namespace TempControl
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create new instance
            TempHumidity TH = new TempHumidity();

            while (true)
            {
                TH.RefreshSensorData();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TempControl.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Iot.Device.DHTxx;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TempControl
{
    public class TempHumidity
    {
        //ToDo: replace the following statement with the desired variable declaration
        public SensorList SensorData { get; set; } = new SensorList();

        private int[] pins = new int[] { 10, 9, 11, 5, 6, 13, 19, 26 };

        public void RefreshSensorData()
        {
            //ToDo: the statement below to clear the data from the list may need to be modified
            //clear existing data
            SensorData.data.Clear();

            foreach (var pin in pins)
            {
                try
                {
                    GetPinData(pin);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw; //re-throw exception
                }
            }
        }

        private void GetPinData(int pin)
        {
            using (Dht11 dht = new Dht11(pin))
            {
                // ToDo: add additional code
                //     ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)
- [Non static class with static fields](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40972/non-static-class-with-static-fields)
- [Q&A: Should I Set Variables to Null to Assist Garbage Collection?](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html)